# Angular 4 Empty Div Element Before a Form Submit

Tags: html, forms, angular, typescript

In the following HTML content, I have a form. I can submit this form to the server which calls a REST API to return some results. The results that I return are paginated using the infinite scroller.

```
<div class="home-page">
  <div class="container page">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-11 col-xs-10">
        <h2>Search</h2>
        <hr>
        <form class="row" name="powerPlantSearchForm" (ngSubmit)="f.valid && searchPowerPlants()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
            <label for="powerPlantName">PowerPlant Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control-small" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !powerPlantName.valid }" name="powerPlantName" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantName" #powerPlantName="ngModel" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
            <label for="powerPlantType">PowerPlant Type</label>
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantType" name="powerPlantType">
              <option value="" disabled>--Select Type--</option>
              <option [ngValue]="powerPlantType" *ngFor="let powerPlantType of powerPlantTypes">
                {{ powerPlantType }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
            <label for="organizationName">Organization Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control-small" name="powerPlantOrganization" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantOrg" #organizationName="ngModel" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
            <label for="powerPlantStatus">PowerPlant Active Status</label>
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantStatus" name="powerPlantStatus">
              <option value="" disabled>--Select Status--</option>
              <option [ngValue]="powerPlantStatus" *ngFor="let powerPlantStatus of powerPlantStatuses">
                {{ powerPlantStatus }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-4">
            <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            <img *ngIf="loading" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAPIAAP///wAAAMLCwkJCQgAAAGJiYoKCgpKSkiH/C05FVFNDQVBFMi4wAwEAAAAh/hpDcmVhdGVkIHdpdGggYWpheGxvYWQuaW5mbwAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAADMwi63P4wyklrE2MIOggZnAdOmGYJRbExwroUmcG2LmDEwnHQLVsYOd2mBzkYDAdKa+dIAAAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAADNAi63P5OjCEgG4QMu7DmikRxQlFUYDEZIGBMRVsaqHwctXXf7WEYB4Ag1xjihkMZsiUkKhIAIfkECQoAAAAsAAAAABAAEAAAAzYIujIjK8pByJDMlFYvBoVjHA70GU7xSUJhmKtwHPAKzLO9HMaoKwJZ7Rf8AYPDDzKpZBqfvwQAIfkECQoAAAAsAAAAABAAEAAAAzMIumIlK8oyhpHsnFZfhYumCYUhDAQxRIdhHBGqRoKw0R8DYlJd8z0fMDgsGo/IpHI5TAAAIfkECQoAAAAsAAAAABAAEAAAAzIIunInK0rnZBTwGPNMgQwmdsNgXGJUlIWEuR5oWUIpz8pAEAMe6TwfwyYsGo/IpFKSAAAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAADMwi6IMKQORfjdOe82p4wGccc4CEuQradylesojEMBgsUc2G7sDX3lQGBMLAJibufbSlKAAAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAADMgi63P7wCRHZnFVdmgHu2nFwlWCI3WGc3TSWhUFGxTAUkGCbtgENBMJAEJsxgMLWzpEAACH5BAkKAAAALAAAAAAQABAAAAMyCLrc/jDKSatlQtScKdceCAjDII7HcQ4EMTCpyrCuUBjCYRgHVtqlAiB1YhiCnlsRkAAAOwAAAAAAAAAAAA==" />
            <button type="button" (click)="resetForm()" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <div>

          <ul id="infinite-scroller" appInfiniteScroller scrollPerecnt="70" [immediateCallback]="true" [scrollCallback]="scrollCallback">
            <li *ngFor="let powerPlant of powerPlants">{{powerPlant.powerPlantName}}</li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now when the user scrolls after loading the first set of results clicking the search button, the calls are made to the server's REST API to fetch additional results. So far so good!

What I want is the following:

The user could enter some other search criteria and click Search button again. Now this time I want to clear the already populated results and show the newly fetched results. When the user scrolls again, I will fetch additional data for the given search criteria and continue hence forth.

Here is my current Typescript!

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { PowerPlantService, UserService } from '../shared';
import { User } from '../shared/models/user.model';
import { PowerPlant } from '../shared/models/powerplant.model';
import {PowerPlantSearchParams} from '../shared/models/powerplantsearchparams.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  // Represents the PowerPlantTypes
  powerPlantTypes = ['RampUpType', 'OnOffType'];
  // Represents the status of a PowerPlant
  powerPlantStatuses = ['Active & Disabled', 'Active', 'Disabled'];
  // Represents the search form
  model: any = {};
  // represents the list of PowerPlant data
  powerPlants: PowerPlant[] = [];
  scrollCallback;

  currentPage = 1;

  constructor(private powerPlantService: PowerPlantService) {
    // this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    // Set the initial values for the drop down fields in the UI
    this.resetForm();

    this.scrollCallback = this.searchPowerPlants.bind(this);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  resetForm() {
    this.model.powerPlantOrg = '';
    this.model.powerPlantName = '';
    this.model.powerPlantType = '';
    this.model.powerPlantStatus = '';
  }

  searchPowerPlants() {
    const powerPlantSearchParams = new PowerPlantSearchParams(
      this.model.powerPlantType,
      this.model.powerPlantOrg,
      this.model.powerPlantName,
      this.model.powerPlantStatus);
/*
    this.powerPlantService.searchPowerPlants(powerPlantSearchParams).subscribe(result => {
      this.powerPlants = <PowerPlant[]> result;
    }); */
    // this.scrollCallback = this.searchPowerPlants.bind(this);
    // const something = this.powerPlantService.searchPowerPlants(powerPlantSearchParams, this.currentPage);
    return this.powerPlantService.searchPowerPlants(powerPlantSearchParams, this.currentPage).do(this.processData);
  }

  private processData = (newPowerPlants) => {
    alert(newPowerPlants);
    this.currentPage++;
    // this.powerPlants = this.powerPlants.concat(newPowerPlants.json());
    this.powerPlants = this.powerPlants.concat(newPowerPlants);
  }

  allPowerPlants(onlyActive: boolean = false, page: number = 1): void {
    this.powerPlantService.allPowerPlants(onlyActive, page).subscribe(result => {
      this.powerPlants = <PowerPlant[]> result;
    });
  }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

EDIT: I tried a different approach, but still could not solve it. What I did is to add another method in the onClick of the search button like this:

And in my Typescript, I empty this array (everything else in my Typescript stays the same):

```
emptyAndBindNew() {
    this.powerPlants = [];
    alert('In empty method');
  }
```

With this approach I get an error:

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: ''. Current value: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]'.
    at viewDebugError (core.es5.js:8421)
    at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.es5.js:8399)
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.es5.js:8563)
    at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.es5.js:12430)
    at checkNoChangesNode (core.es5.js:12404)
    at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.es5.js:13181)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:13083)
    at Object.View_HomeComponent_0._co [as updateDirectives] (HomeComponent.html:45)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13065)
    at checkNoChangesView (core.es5.js:12224)
```

Comment: add **this.powerPlants = [];** inside the searchPowerPlants() method.

Comment: Nope! That does not work! There was somebody that posted your suggestion as an answer and he deleted his post later on! Please read my question carefully before you post! Notice that I have a scroller which keeps calling the searchPowerPlants() function and I do not want to reset it on every call, but only on the first call that happens by clicking the button!